# VBA code to paste a range into Excel as an array?

Tags: arrays, excel, vba

So I have a range of items plugged in an Excel spreadsheet and I am looking for some code to paste those same values as an array (i.e. a ctrl + shift + enter formula) elsewhere in my spreadsheet. I've been trying to use the Range.FormulaArray property but can't seem to get it to work.

As an example, I have a list of text items such as:

Apple

Orange

Banana

And I want to paste these items as a hardcoded array elsewhere in the spreadsheet so that the formula in cell A1 will read:

={"Apple";"Orange";"Banana"}

And the values will spill in to the subsequent two cells

I'm using the latest version of Office 365.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Use `.Formula2`:

```
Sub EasyAsOneTwoThree()
    Range("A1").Formula2 = "={""Apple"";""Orange"";""Banana""}"
End Sub
```

[image]

As you see, it spills down very nicely.

*(notice I had to double-up on the double quotes)*

Comment: Double quotations is the VB(A) way of escaping a quotation mark. When you want to print a single quotation mark you use two quotation marks and it will print a single quotation mark instead of interpreting it as a closure to your string. I think it is important to clarify this rather than simply stating "I had to double-up."